# why when I use count result is empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

my sample code is like this:

```
select count(*) cnt
from
(
    select title,person,first_value,second_value,third_value
    from
    (
        select a.title,b.person,b.id_meta b_meta,b.value
        from tbl_one a
        inner join tbl_param b on a.param=b.id
        where b.id in ('first_value','second_value','third_value')
    ) x
    pivot
    (
        sum(value)
        for param in ([first_value],[second_value],[third_value])
    ) pvt
) r
inner join tbl_two c on r.person=c.person
inner join tbl_person p on r.person=p.id
group by p.title,r.first_value,r.second_value,r.third_value
```

this code did not have count, I took a string from this code that is empty, when I count this query I suppose to get 0 but it only shows a empty string. why it give me empty instead of 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, nor a string value.  So, your question is a bit suspicious.

I assume that the issue is slightly different -- your query returns no rows at all.  Then, when you go to look at `COUNT()` it will be returned as `NULL` (particularly if you are using it as a scalar subquery) because the row does not exist.

This can happen when you have a `GROUP BY` clause.  If all rows are filtered out, then no rows are returned.

I would suggest that you remove the `GROUP BY` clause and count the number of rows being returned.  I suspect the value is `0`.

Comment: thanks man! yes group by make my result empty string, when I deleted group by part my result shown as 0! thank you very much :)